# Universal family of hash functions — dependent on table size?

Tags: hash, hash-tables, hashing

> Given the following family of hash functions:
>
> $$
> \mathbb{H} = \{h_c(x) = (12x + c) \bmod 
> m \mid c \in \mathbb{N} \},
>     $$
> where $m$ is the key size.
>
> Prove that $\mathbb{H}$ is not a universal family of hash functions.

So I got the following idea:

If $m = 12 $ then $H$ is not an universal family of hash functions. But is this enough or have I to prove it for every/random m?

This leads to the question: Is a universal family of hash functions dependent on the hash table size?

Comment: *Is this enough?* You should ask whoever set you the exercise to clarify this point.

Comment: Since the hash is used to index an index in a hash table, the range of the hash function should match the size of the hash table. In practice, this is accomplished by computing a long hash and reducing it modulo the size of the hash table.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately this is a question for the person who posed the exercise. They need to specify if they are asking "Is H non-universal for all m?" or if they are asking "Is H universal for all m?"

If they're asking the former, then you proving H is non-universal for m = 12 is not enough. If they're asking the latter, it is.